# Speed up expensive IEnumerable<T> operation

Tags: c#, performance, ienumerable

I am working on a C# library that recursively enumerates the subfolders of a remote share over the network. This is an expensive operation, and there may be thousands of folders to be traversed. The method that carries out this work for the client returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, and uses lazy evaluation (as is often the case with `IEnumerable<T>`, so the call itself returns very quickly, but then, when the client executes a `foreach` loop or a `Take()` call on the return value, things get pretty slow.

I am looking for approaches to speed this up. Some ideas include:

1. Avoid lazy enumeration by making my library retrieve all items and store them in a `List<string>`, for example, before it is returned to the client. This would make the method call much slower, but iteration much faster.
2. Drop the functionality to enumerate all the subfolders, and require that the client specifies some kind of filter that limits the number of items to traverse.
3. Use an altogether different method to enumerate folders which avoids `IEnumerable<T>`.

I have run out of ideas. What approach would you suggest to make this work, and fast? Thank you.

Comment: Doing the work earlier won't make it any faster, it'll just change *when* you do the work.  As for whether or not you actually need to do that work, we can't tell you that, *you* need to tell *us* what the code needs to do.

Comment: have you tried doing it in parallel? at least for each root folder start a separate thread / task . maybe have a look at TPL Dataflow library. Like @Servy said: you're requirements aren't quite clear. If it's okay to ask the client for a filter than that sounds reasonable

Comment: Did you try to enumerable all folders as IEnumerable<IList<string>> where first IEnumerable was Lazy and all IList<> enumerated parallelly on the server' side?

Comment: You can perform enumeration in background into queue and push items to consumer when they are ready. That way it will may be a bit faster, because while consumer does something with current item - you already fetching next items.

Comment: @woelliJ: Many thanks. I hadn't thought of using parallel threads. I will try that.

Comment: @Evk: Interesting approach, although a bit tricky to implement maybe? I'll give it a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of Client-Server communications.

Using `IEnumerable` as an interface is fine.

Option #2 is the most performant general solution. If the remote folders change infrequently, then consider implementing caching on the query results.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of caching results, so this is useful.